# BEM class chainability

Tags: css, naming-conventions, semantics, bem

I've recently played around BEM syntax, And I was wondering about the use of chainability in CSS, as I try to use the `class=*^` & `class=*` selector in order to obtain a more free CSS class order.

eg:

```
[class^="btn"][class*="--default"][class*="--outline"] {/* style */}
```

So that

```
<button class="btn--default--outline">Button</button>
```

or

```
<button class="btn--outline--default">Button</button>
```

would be similar.

And what would be more readable than:

```
<button class="btn btn--default btn--outline">Button</button>
```

This guy is using [the same concept](http://viget.com/extend/bem-multiple-modifiers-and-experimenting-with-attribute-selectors) but everybody seems to disagree while not advancing real source for their argument (slow? anti-html conform? anti-semantic?).

So is there reasons not to use this syntax?

Comment: Why do you want to obtain "a more free css class order"?

Comment: well, it's more about avoiding repeating the element name (btn btn--default btn-...) and using a modular class "btn--default--..."). It's basically about DRY coding.

Comment: I don't do this because it's verbose. The time and bloat you save when writing markup is instead moved to your CSS.

Comment: Then I don't see a point in using BEM, if you could just use regular classes — `class="btn default outline"` — and then reference them in a DRY way through `.btn`, `.btn.default`, `.btn.outline`, `.btn.default.outline`, etc. The point of BEM is to specifically avoid this.

Comment: but using regular class would use multiples class, instead of using a single class for an element like btn--default--outline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should avoid your technique because [attribute selectors are slower than class selectors](http://jsperf.com/class-vs-attributes-css-selectors). And also, I suspect that the attribute selectors with "^=" or "*=" can not be performant on huge DOM, in the same way that a "LIKE" in SQL is not as effective as a "=" on an indexed column. (And strange ways are always more difficult to write and to maintain).

I suggest [this BEM syntax](http://paleo.casa/pleasant-bem.html):

- BlockName
- BlockName.-modifierName
- BlockName-elementName
- BlockName-elementName.-modifierName

With this syntax, your example becomes:

```
<button class="Btn -default -outline">Button</button>
```

NB: Modifiers should not be styled independently of their block or element, because this practice would not been conform to the BEM methodology. If `-outline` is a transversal class, make it a block:

```
<button class="Btn -default Outline">Button</button>
```

Comment: Ugly is an opinion, and maintaining / writing can be easily achieved by some SASS mixin (look the at link in my question). Would happen to have some source about the performances argument?

Comment: That's what I was looking for. If you edit your response in order to emphase the performance argument (add links/doc), you'll get the green check!